# how to make Firestore Persitence work with Progressive Web App made with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, persistence, progressive-web-apps

I made an app with vuejs, that is by the way awesome.
it uses a firebase auth with local persistence, 
and a firestore database with persistence enabled also.
Everything seems to work fine.
I decided to make a PWA from it so people can use it offline,
the assets are loaded from cache, i have the installation banner.
My problem is that the firestore persistence is not workingfine.

- Problem 1 : When offline, when i insert a member to firestore "members" collection, the ui is not refreshing (once i get back online, the user is in the list, so the persistence worked partially)
- Problem 2 : The list of members. When offline, the app cannot access to a persistent 
  version of "members" collection.

This list is loaded when the app is loading, but after refresh, it disappears.
What is the best approach to achieve this issue?
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:
i created a method :

```
realtimeListenerMembres() {
      // real-time listener
      let self = this;
      this.$firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("membres")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          //console.log(snapshot.docChanges());

          snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            if (change.type === "added") {
              self.membres.push({
                ...change.doc.data(),
                id: change.doc.id,
              });
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
              // remove the document data from the web page
            }
            self.sendToGroupe();
          });
        });
```

ant i put the cal in "created" cycle.

```
created() {
    this.realitimeListenerGroupe();
    this.realtimeListenerMembres();
    this.realtimeListenerReunions();
  },
```

Now persistense is ok for assets an for firestore.
The pwa can work totally offline, and then sync with firestore when 
internet connexion goes back.